# Momentum in Cylindrical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, momentum, coordinate-systems

Given a curve $r(t) = \left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right)$. Respectively writing it in cylindric coordinates $r(t) = \left(\begin{array}{c}\rho\,\cos(\varphi)\\\rho\,\sin(\varphi)\\z\end{array}\right)$ Now what's the momentum? Is it really that ease to state $p = m\,\dot{r}$ thus $p = m\,\left(\begin{array}{c}\dot{\rho}\,\cos(\varphi)-\rho\,\dot{\varphi}\,\sin(\varphi) \\\dot{\rho}\,\sin(\varphi)+\rho\,\dot{\varphi}\,\cos(\varphi)\\1\end{array}\right)$ ? Something feels wrong about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks right except that the third coordinate should be $\dot{z}$.